# Fail on simple Hello world "Swift build" command

Tags: swift3

This is the error i am getting on a simple execution of the following command

> $ swift build

```
The Error: 
error: popen(arguments: ["/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc", "--driver-mode=swift", "-I", "/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm", "-L", "/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm", "-lPackageDescription", "-target", "x86_64-apple-macosx10.10", "/Users/medampudi/Dropbox/MobileApp/OpenSourceSwift/HelloWorld/Package.swift", "-fileno", "5"], posix_spawn error: No such file or directory (2), `["/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc", "--driver-mode=swift", "-I", "/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm", "-L", "/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm", "-lPackageDescription", "-target", "x86_64-apple-macosx10.10", "/Users/medampudi/Dropbox/MobileApp/OpenSourceSwift/HelloWorld/Package.swift", "-fileno", "5"]`)
```

this was encountered on MacOS Sierra Swift 3.1.1 with xcode8.3.2 setup any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Close the bug. Did a reinstall and it took care of the problem. A restart is however recommended after the install.